# C zlib gzfwrite() alternative?

Tags: c, linux, zlib

I'm working on an assignment for class that involves sending .gz binary data from a server to a client using a socket. On the client end, it receives the stream and stores it into an unsigned char buffer. How can I write this compressed data into a new .gz file on the client side?

I can't use gzfwrite() because it was added in 2017 and the old ass machines they're using here to grade my program don't have zlib that recently updated. Any attempt to use it yields "undefined reference".

I've tried using fopen():

```c
FILE *gz = fopen("test.gz", "wb");  // create new .gz on client end
fwrite(buffer, 1, buflen, gz);  // buffer contains binary data sent from server
fclose(gz);
```

but calling `gunzip` on the resulting .gz fails since `file test.gz` outputs `test.gz: data`; as in it's not recognized as a .gz file.

I don't think gzprintf() will work either since it expects a null terminated string, and I have binary data. Ideally I'd like to just sent .gz from the server and write that info to a new .gz file on the client. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the server is sending the whole file you don't need any other libraries to write it back to a file. Your `fwrite` approach looks correct. If it doesn't work then you are doing something else wrong. But we can't tell what without a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(buffer, 1, buflen, gz);`  most likely, the whole `buffer` was not filled via some `read()` operation.  What should be used is the count of bytes read that was returned from the call to `read()` (after testing that variable for 0 and <0 and possibly handling those errors.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: You can compile  a newer  `zlib` on the target machine. It is coded in C, and the source code is downloadable

Answer (score 1):

Use `gzwrite(gz, buffer, buflen)` instead. That function has been there since time immemorial.